# String Buffer To String Conversion Exception?

Tags: java, arraylist, stringbuffer

Hi Check the below code

```
   ArrayList x=new ArrayList();
   ArrayList<String>y=x;
   ArrayList<StringBuffer>z=x;
   y.add("Strings");
   System.out.println(z.get(0).toString());
```

Am getting Class Cast Exception at System.out.println

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
 at com.one.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:16)
```

But when i am trying

```
  System.out.println(z.get(0))
```

it is working
why this coming ??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please don't use a StringBuffer when you can use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are doing that as an experiment (if not then read the other answers as to how you should have written your code).

x is a raw `ArrayList`, in which you can place any types of objects.

`y.add("string")` adds a String.

z is an `ArrayList<StringBuffer>` and expects StringBuffers. When you call `z.get(0)`, the JVM tries to cast the element at index 0 to a StringBuffer before returning it. That cast fails.

In other words, although `StringBuffer s = z.get(0);` compiles, it will throw a ClassCastException at runtime because `z.get(0)` is not a `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

The specifics as to why you are getting your problem is this:

- New ArrayList is created, empty
- All elements are typed to String in y
- All elements are typed to StringBuffer in z
- A new element is added to this array list.
- The JVM attempts to cast it to BOTH String and StringBuffer
- Because "Strings" is not an instance of StringBuffer, ClassCastException is thrown.

To avoid this, do not have an array typed to both String and StringBuffer. Select only one. For example:

```
ArrayList<StringBuffer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<StringBuffer>
```

If you want to copy a String arraylist into a StringBuffer ArrayList, you'll have to iterate over all of the items in z to convert them to string buffers:

```
ArrayList x=new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String>y=x;
ArrayList<StringBuffer>z=new ArrayList<StringBuffer>();
for(String s : y)
    z.add(new StringBuffer(s));
```

The reason for this is that StringBuffer does not extent String. What's causing a problem is that you cannot cast a string, say "str" to a StringBuffer i.e. you cannot do `StringBuffer s = (StringBuffer)"str";`.

To cast `ArrayList x` to `ArrayList<T>`, all elements of `x` must be extend or be an instance of `T`.

In addition, you should always use generic types, when possible. If you don't know what will be (for example) in the list, use:

```
ArrayList<?> x = new ArrayList<?>();
```

If you know a little bit more, such as that it will be a subclass of another class, use
`ArrayList<? extends T>` or `ArrayList<? implements T>`. This will help you avoid future ClassCastExceptions.